# getting the latest download url and version of a software from a website with powershell

Tags: powershell, url, version, invoke-webrequest

> I want to take the take the latest version of the software and check with the version that is installed on system if it is newer install the new version .

''' $web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.webex.com/downloads/jabber/jabber-vdi.html"
( $latest = $web.AllElements | Where-Object {$_.TagName -eq "li"} | Select-String "Jabber Windows client" | Select -first 1 )'''

> for taking the version number and url I've wrote these but does not work

''' ( $latestversion = $latest.Context | Select-String -pattern "\d\d.\d")
( $downloadUrl=$latest.Context | Select-String -pattern "\w.msi" )'''

> also I have tried this way but does not work

'''$latestversion = $latest.links.href '''

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Links property to view all retrieved links, then filter it to select only those ending with "msi"

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.webex.com/downloads/jabber/jabber-vdi.html").Links | Where-Object href -like '*msi' | select -First 1 | select -expand href
```

edit: to get both, maybe use ParsedHtml like so:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.webex.com/downloads/jabber/jabber-vdi.html").ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByClassName('vdi-links')[0].innerHTML -match "<LI>(\d{1,2}\.\d).*(https.*msi)"
write-host "Version $($Matches[1]) available at $($Matches[2])"
```

`$Matches` is an automatic variable which contains the result of the `-match` regex. The brackets in the match define our match groups, so for our regex of `"<LI>(\d{1,2}\.\d).*(https.*msi)"`:

Our first match is `(\d{1,2}\.\d)` where `\d` is any number and {1,2} means match either 1 or 2 (so we could match "9" or "10"), `\.` matches the dot character literally

Our second match is `(https.*msi)` where `.` matches any character and `*` means match any number of occurances.

Comment: thanks ,Do you have any idea about getting the version number, I found <  $WebVersion = $result.Content | Select-String -Pattern "\d\d.\d" | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value -as [version] } > but it does not work

Comment: I've updated the answer for you